# Glassfish4 JMX Configuration using asadmin

Tags: glassfish-4, asadmin

I have Glassfish4 and want make JMX to listen only to localhost and diable TLS and Security via asaadmin.

I can do the same via Admin Web UI, but not sure how to do that via asadim.

The below command updates the jmx-connecter property under `admin-config` but I need a similar change under `default-config`.

`asadmin set server.admin-service.jmx-connector.system.security-enabled=false`

The above update the domain.xml under

```
   <config name="server-config">
.....
  <admin-service system-jmx-connector-name="system" type="das-and-server">
        <jmx-connector address="localhost" port="8686" name="system" auth-realm-name="admin-realm" security-enabled="false">
          <ssl tls-enabled="false" classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.GlassfishSSLImpl" client-auth="want" cert-nickname="server"></ssl>
        </jmx-connector>
        <property name="adminConsoleContextRoot" value="/admin"></property>
        <property name="adminConsoleDownloadLocation" value="${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/lib/install/applications/admingui.war"></property>
        <property name="ipsRoot" value="${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/.."></property>
        <das-config></das-config>
      </admin-service>
....
    </config>
```

I need to update values under `default-config` like this

```
    <config name="default-config">
    .....
      <admin-service system-jmx-connector-name="system">
            <jmx-connector address="localhost" port="${JMX_SYSTEM_CONNECTOR_PORT}" name="system" auth-realm-name="admin-realm" security-enabled="false">
              <ssl ssl3-enabled="false" tls-enabled="false" classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.GlassfishSSLImpl" client-auth="want" cert-nickname="glassfish-instance"></ssl>
            </jmx-connector>
            <property name="adminConsoleDownloadLocation" value="${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/lib/install/applications/admingui.war"></property>
            <das-config></das-config>
          </admin-service>
    ....
   </config>
```

Please, guide me on how to do this via CLI using asadmin.

If this helps: Top update the same from the Admin UI --> Configurations --> default-config --> JMX Connector / SSL.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a lot, found out.

`asadmin set configs.config.default-config.admin-service.jmx-connector.system.address=localhost`

`asadmin set configs.config.default-config.admin-service.jmx-connector.system.security-enabled=false`